# To do something by one's own choice

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-structure, sentence-usage

Suppose you have resigned your job position and left your working area. After a while, you encounter with a colleague of that job; he / she asks you about the reason you left that e.g. office. (throughout their conversations with you, it's clear that they think you've been fired whereas you were not and you did it by your own will and subsequently you're going to let them know this fact); I was wondering if you could let me know if in this sense the self-made sentence bellow sounds natural or not:

> - I left **by my own choice**.

My second scenario:
Imagine a person is competing for a party of a constitution. A friend of him comes to him and asks why he has joined the opposite group which even has lesser financial benefits for him in comparison with the previous party. He says:

> - At first it wasn't how much I would earn; the only thing I wanted was joining them; I did it **by my own choice**.

Does the above sentence work here properly? (Especially the bold parts)

Comment: I think "I decided to leave." or "I decided to do it." is sufficient to get the idea across.

Answer (score 1):

"Went" would not be the correct word to use.

You could use

> I left by my own choice.
>   I left on my own accord.
>   I left of my own volition.
>   I chose to leave.
>   I quit.

You could preface it my saying "They didn't fire me".

> They didn't fire me, I left on my own accord.

Comment: Thank you @Peter ; Please answer my second scenario too; I altered my question; meanwhile please let me know about "by my own free will"? Does it work either?

Comment: @A-friend _On my own accord,_ and _of my own accord_ are by far the best ways to express this in English. (By the way, **Bellow** is a verb in English, comes from Middle English, and means **to roar like a bull.** Be sure not to write _bellow_ when you mean _below,_ which means "beneath.")

Comment: @P.E.Dant did you mean for both of my scenarios?

Comment: Yes, for both of them.

Comment: @P.E.Dant thank you very much for being of help. ;)

Answer (score 0):

For professional level jobs, the most common form of words for the first scenario would involve the verb “to resign”. For example:

> Oh no, they didn’t fire me. **I resigned**.

For the second scenario, it’s not clear to me what you are asking. For example, exactly what do you mean by “a party of a constitution”? At first sight that looks like you’re referring to someone in politics. But that doesn’t seem to fit with what you go on to say about financial benefits. If you clarify, I’d be happy to revisit this answer.